# Customizing Move Hotkey

Tags: customization, shortcut

I'm new to Blender and I'd love for Move to be <kbd>M</kbd> not <kbd>G</kbd>. I've done edit> preferences > Input > Transform Modal Map > Mode > changed the input to M instead of G. And it has had no effect. I even made sure to turn off the M input for "move active object to collection". What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest not to do it, just learn the default controls otherwise good luck following tutorials and finding answers when you get stuck. Also M is super far on the right of the keyboard, while your left hand should usually be on the left, which makes it a really bad shortcut for moving.

Answer (score 2):

i think you have to remove every other keybinding to "M" so there are no conflicts.

For me,

3dview -> object mode-> move to collection is blocking

but I would advise you to use "G" for G.rab as it is, because it's not Move - it is grab. You grab stuff in all Editor windows and then you move it around… Keyframes in DopeSheet, or things in the Viewport and I belive in you, you will adjust your Habits and you will handle that.
In a few weeks you will not go back.
You will G -> X ->5 and R -> Y ->90 and G-> Z -> 4 like a Pro!

Comment: I have to agree with this, if you change the default keymap and you want to use the feature mapped then when you ask others or search online you'll be different to everybody else

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback, I'll try to stick with the defaults then. I did remove the other conflict for move to collection, so I was curious as to what else could have been causing the issue.

Comment: It's a really good idea to stick with this one. It really works everywhere so changing it in all ediitors might be more work than it seems and there could be many more conflicts. It might also get quite confusing if you leave inconsistencies in some places. I think making a new habit to use default g is a lot easier than the alternative.